# Finding Local Minimum

Tags: derivatives

I have a function,

$f(x)=2x+4\cos(x), x\in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$

By differentiation,

$f'(x)=2-4\sin(x)$ and

$f''(x)=-4\cos(x)$

By using $f'(x)=0$ method, I found $x=\pi/6$ as the **local maximum**. I couldn't find the local minimum using $f''(-\pi/2)$ and $f''(\pi/2)$ because both tends to $0$. Does the function have a local minimum?.

Comment: plug $x=-\pi/2$ in the given function

Comment: At the end points you don't need to check the derivatives, just evaluate the function and compare. In general, there is no derivatives at the end points, just one sided derivatives, since the function isn't defined on the other side.